# How to fix iTunes library? I copied the iTunes folder but the music does not appear in iTunes

Tags: folders, itunes

I copied my iTunes folder and changed it in preferences. Then I did Library -> Organize Library. Why doesn't iTunes see the music? (I think I used this process before).

How to fix?

Using iTunes 10.

Comment: Copied from where, to where?

Comment: From one hard drive to another. The old one is being removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should have done is hold the <kbd>⌥</kbd>-key while starting iTunes and it will prompt you to choose a new library which is the `iTunes Library.itl` inside the iTunes folder you wanted to copy. If you still have a copy of the old folder, do the above. Otherwise, I think you just created a new library with 0 songs.

Comment: Will this preserve my playlists and ratings?

Comment: @BSeven I am not familiar with the ratings details. But I think all the information is stored into the iTunes library file. Pointing the iTunes to a new library file shouldn't harm any of your previous setup until you ask it to for example consolidate. So just point to the old library and find out if it has all the information you're worried about loosing.

Comment: Yes, it should preserve everything. Note that in some cases, you won't be able to select the old iTunes library. Old versions of iTunes called the file inside the folder **iTunes Library**, not **iTunes Library.itl**. If this happens to you, just add the extension.

Comment: For Windows hold down `Shift-` while opening iTunes.